# ENOTFOUND Error on startup Secure Gateway Client on Docker container using Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, ibm-cloud, secure-gateway, ibm-cloud-kubernetes

I have a single Docker container running (into a VPN network) on Bluemix to run my Secure Gateway Client in order to stabilish a VPN connection between Cloud to Site and it's working.

I'm trying to migrate this container to run on Kubernetes because IBM will deprecate single docker instances on Bluemix. But running the same image into a Kubernetes Cluster a get the error bellow:

[2017-10-02 13:52:11.766] [ERROR] (Client ID 17) The response is code: ENOTFOUND, message: getaddrinfo

Does anyone knows what is happening? The secure gateway client image I'm using is "ibmcom/secure-gateway-client"

Thanks,

Comment: `getaddrinfo` implies a DNS resolution error. How is your DNS configured in your cluster?

Comment: Hello jaxxstornm, I'm using the default configuration: I found "dnsPolicy": "ClusterFirst" in my json Pod config. Beyond that, I did nothing about DNS configuration. Is threre anything more to setup?